# AntD Carousel only displays the first div in it

Tags: antd

This is the `Carousel` gist from my code.

```
<Carousel arrows={true}>
                <div className='new-offers-item'>
                  <div className='new-offers-item-bg'>
                    <div className='new-offers-item-rent-tag'>TEXT HERE</div>
                    <div className='new-offers-item-favourite' />
                    <div className='new-offers-posted-at'>ANOTHER TEXT HERE, 10:44</div>
                  </div>
                  <div className='new-offers-item-location-rate'>
                    <div className='new-offers-item-location'>street address, 5<br />CC Espiral,<br /> 1 floor</div>
                    <div className='new-offers-item-rate'>
                      <div>
                        <span className='new-offers-item-rate-value'>240 000 </span>
                        <span className='new-offers-item-rate-unit'>abcd.</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className='new-offers-item-city-street'>
                    <span>City</span>
                    <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    <span>Address1</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className='new-offers-item-description'>
                    <div className='new-offers-item-description-row'>
                      <div className='new-offers-item-description-row-space'>
                        <div className='new-offers-item-description-row-space-division'>
                          <div>
                            <img src={sqM} />
                          </div>
                          <p>
                            <span>Total</span>
                            <span>600</span>
                          </p>
                          <p>
                            <span>&nbsp;</span>
                            <span className='span-divider'>/</span>
                          </p>
                          <p>
                            <span>Sale</span>
                            <span>300</span>
                          </p>
                        </div>
                        <div className='new-offers-item-description-row-metre-rate'>
                          <p>
                            <span>Per meter</span>
                          </p>
                          <p>
                            <span>6 700 </span>
                            <span>unit<sup>2</sup></span>
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className='new-offers-item-description-row'>
                        <div className='new-offers-item-description-row-space'>
                          <div className='new-offers-item-description-row-space-division'>
                            <div className='new-offers-item-description-second'>
                              <img src={bldgIcon} />
                              <span className='item-type'>Торговый центр</span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div className='new-offers-item-description-row-metre-rate'>
                            <div className='new-offers-item-description-second'>
                              <img src={doorsIcon} />
                              <span className='item-type'>10 floor</span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className='new-offers-item'>
                  <div className='new-offers-item-bg'>
                    <div className='new-offers-item-rent-tag'>TEXT HERE</div>
                    <div className='new-offers-item-favourite' />
                    <div className='new-offers-posted-at'>ANOTHER TEXT HERE, 10:44</div>
                  </div>
                  <div className='new-offers-item-location-rate'>
                    <div className='new-offers-item-location'>street address, 5<br />CC Espiral,<br /> 1 floor</div>
                    <div className='new-offers-item-rate'>
                      <div>
                        <span className='new-offers-item-rate-value'>240 000 </span>
                        <span className='new-offers-item-rate-unit'>abcd.</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className='new-offers-item-city-street'>
                    <span>City</span>
                    <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    <span>Address1</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className='new-offers-item-description'>
                    <div className='new-offers-item-description-row'>
                      <div className='new-offers-item-description-row-space'>
                        <div className='new-offers-item-description-row-space-division'>
                          <div>
                            <img src={sqM} />
                          </div>
                          <p>
                            <span>Total</span>
                            <span>600</span>
                          </p>
                          <p>
                            <span>&nbsp;</span>
                            <span className='span-divider'>/</span>
                          </p>
                          <p>
                            <span>Sale</span>
                            <span>300</span>
                          </p>
                        </div>
                        <div className='new-offers-item-description-row-metre-rate'>
                          <p>
                            <span>Per meter</span>
                          </p>
                          <p>
                            <span>6 700 </span>
                            <span>unit<sup>2</sup></span>
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className='new-offers-item-description-row'>
                        <div className='new-offers-item-description-row-space'>
                          <div className='new-offers-item-description-row-space-division'>
                            <div className='new-offers-item-description-second'>
                              <img src={bldgIcon} />
                              <span className='item-type'>Торговый центр</span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div className='new-offers-item-description-row-metre-rate'>
                            <div className='new-offers-item-description-second'>
                              <img src={doorsIcon} />
                              <span className='item-type'>7 floor</span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Carousel>
```

Only the first `div.new-offers-item` gets displayed.
How do I get the second one and others to display?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the soultion that produced the desired outcome. Added 2 more 
`.new-offers-item`.

```
const carouselSettings = {
      arrows: true,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    };
```

Then add the `const carouselSettings` to the `Carousel` component:

`<Carousel {...carouselSettings}>...</Carousel>`.

Based on `react-slick` docs and playground at https://github.com/akiran/react-slick.

AntD Carousel doesn't place the arrows to the html layout when the number of items inside the Carousel equals to `slidesToShow`. The arrows which are `button`s are `transparent` by default you'd need to put an arrow image inside the `button`s. The css classes for `button`s are `.ant-carousel .slick-prev` and `.ant-carousel .slick-next`.

Comment: We are discussing about Antd carousel library, not slick slider bro.

Answer (score 1):

It is as designed. This shows the first item as current and to move to the next item, you can click on the navigation.
You can set the background of new-offers-item to see the navigation. You can refer to the example here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nn44020wzp

Comment: Thank you. How do I set the `Carousel` to display 3 `.new-offers-item` before navigating to the next 3 ? Is wrapping the 3 `.new-offers-item` to the one containing `div` the only way?

Comment: I think so and you need to add css so your 3 items will stand in line

Comment: I added `display: flex` only now the Slick Carousel arrows are gone. Not transparent I don't find them in the html layout.

Comment: I guess it is as expected since you have only one "big" item. what do you want to achieve? maybe you are looking to show several items at a time?

Comment: Linking to CodeSandbox is fine, but you really should include the most relevant portions of the solution in your answer.

Comment: I just provided a sample to explain how carousel works. And it seems that El wants doing something further more. Btw I updated to reflect what I meant with the most recent question

Comment: I wanted a carousel of a look of `<  item item item  >`. Would also want to hide the arrows when the first/last element is the first/last on the current display. Is this achievable with AntD?

Comment: @duc mai Could you comment on what you did on Codesandbox please? Did you wrap 2 `div`s inside `Carousel` to a wrapping `div` or was there smth more than that? I couldn't see the arrows on the Codesandbox example.

Comment: what I did were
- wrap two divs into one
- display: flex important for the wrapper
- flexbasis: 50% for the children
it seems that you found what you need yourself :)

Comment: How did u achieve < item item item > with arrows? @ElAnonimo

Answer (score 1):

Since antd using slick slider for their Carousel, you should refer to their [API](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/)

To be more precise, you will need to use prop: "slidesToShow" in order to show the numbers of slides that you need.

For Example:

```
const settings = {
      dots: true,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1
};
```